# Is it possible to code on both Window and Linux with ONE project? (using Yarn, React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operating-system, development-environment, yarnpkg

I'm a beginner for programming.I use two computers with different operating systems; Windows and Ubuntu.

Working on React using Yarn, now I'm just working on each OS and merging them using Copy and Paste.
However, I want to work for one project on both OS.

Are there any problems to do that?
Or Are there any ways to work on both OS? (I guess, adding some code for javascript environment or for something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I do it all the time. I have a Windows PC at work and Linux PC at home.
Reactjs projects depend upon Nodejs, but not the host OS, except some Nodejs path variables in env. So as long as you have a proper Nodejs setup, it works exactly same.

Comment: This is what I exactly wanted to know:) So it depends upon only node js! Is path variable the only one problem? I thought that there will be more problems which derives from different OS version of Yarn.

Comment: i use nvm , node version manager , which controls entire node js versions on machine. so . even in older and newer version of node js i can control version accordingly to the project

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you have two computers and you want a way to code on both of them without copy/paste the entire project from one to another.

If that what you want then you need a **Source version control**. Here one of them: https://git-scm.com/

Install that software on both of your computers, then sign up a https://github.com/ account.

Now, each time you finished your code, submit your code to your Github account via the Git software (you'll have to learn how to use it). And then when you are using another computer, you can simply **pull** your project from your Github account and continue your coding.

My answer here simply shows you what should be done, you'll have to learn a lot about Git and Github to accomplish your wish.